# Creating a 2 column df from a loop of unique values

Tags: r

I am looking to create a matrix `babyList` storing the number of unique names in the `babynames` package for every `year` in that package. I am only interested in **using a loop** to do this.

```
   library(babynames) 
###### Here I create the matrix where I want my output to be in
    babyList <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=2,nrow=range(babynames$year[2]-range(babynames$year[1])),))
    colnames(babyList) <- c("years","unique names")
```

The for loop is giving me trouble. Here is what I know it will need:

###### Pseudo code

```
for (i in babynames$year) {
length(unique(babynames$name[babynames$year == i]

}
```

How can I put this all together in a correct structure?

Comment: `aggregate(name~year, babynames, function(x) length(unique(x)))` Using `dplyr` - `babynames %>% group_by(year) %>%summarise(n = n_distinct(name))`

Comment: I am interested only in doing this with a loop

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `dplyr::summarise()` instead:

```
library(babynames)
library(dplyr)

babynames %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(unique_names = length(unique(name)))
```

which gives the number of unique names for each year in the babynames dataset:

```
# A tibble: 138 x 2
    year unique_names
 * <dbl>        <int>
 1  1880         1889
 2  1881         1830
 3  1882         2012
 4  1883         1962
 ...
```

Comment: Is there a way I could do  this from a loop?

Comment: Thank you, that works. However I got it working without calling the variable unique_names.

babynames %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(length(unique(name)))